# Is injection attack possible with file_get_content?

Tags: php, laravel, file-get-contents, code-injection

```
class TemplateController
{
    public function get(string $template): string
    {
        return file_get_contents(_DIST . '/resources/templates/' . $template . '.html');
    }
}
```

I use $_GET or a direct argument to the address bar to import a template from SPA application. Can this cause problems?

I use quotes around the input to run commend to access inaccessible files, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be possible for someone to pass a value to the `$template` variable that used `../` or `/` to navigate out of the directory you have set in the parameter.

In theory they could navigate up to more vulnerable directories and access files you don't want them to.
I would say the best approach to secure against that would be to validate against the input string containing `../` or `/`
If you know the file name will never have any `.` or `/` characters in you could throw a validation error for any string containing any `.` or `/` characters.

On top of that, following best practices around setting up your users and permissions on your production server will help to protect you.
This thread offers some useful help there:
[How to set up file permissions for Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel)

Other than that I can't think of any other vulnerabilities... anyone else?

Comment: Updated answer with some helpful stuff on best practices around file permissions on your server. Well worth being sure you've got that right too.